# How to find probability of predicted weight of a link in weighted graph

Tags: machine-learning, graph-theory, weighted-average, weighted-graph

I have an undirected weighted graph. Let's say node A and node B don't have a direct link between them but there are paths connects both nodes through other intermediate nodes. Now I want to predict the possible weight of the direct link between the node A and B as well as the probability of it.

I can predict the weight by finding the possible paths and their average weight but how can I find the probability of it
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are describing is called ***link prediction***. [Here](http://be.amazd.com/link-prediction/) is a short tutorial explaining about the problem and some simple heuristics that can be used to solve it.

Since this is an open-ended problem, these simple solutions can be improved a lot by using more complicated techniques. Another approach for predicting the probability for an edge is to use Machine Learning rather than rule-based heuristics.

A recent article called [node2vec](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/node2vec-kdd16.pdf), proposed an algorithm that maps each node in a graph to a dense vector (aka **embedding**). Then, by applying some binary operator on a pair of nodes, we get an edge representation (another vector). This vector is then used as input features to some classifier that predicts the edge-probability. The paper compared a few such binary operators over a few different datasets, and significantly outperformed the heuristic benchmark scores across all of these datasets.

The code to compute embeddings given your graph can be found [here](https://github.com/aditya-grover/node2vec).

Comment: I'd add my own implementation for Python3, can be found [here](https://github.com/eliorc/node2vec)